# php error "syntax error unexpected 'public' (t_public) expecting end of file"

Tags: php

I have a error when add this code and i dont what is the error please i need help this is the code

```
    public function hookActionDispatcher($params = []){
       $payments_controllers = [
        'ps_wirepaymentvalidationModuleFrontController',
        'ps_checkpaymentvalidationModuleFrontController',
       ];
       if($params['controller_type'] == Dispatcher::FC_FRONT &&
         in_array($params['controller_class'], $payments_controllers) &&
         $params['is_module']){
         $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
          if($cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice){
          $cart->id_address_delivery = 6;
          $cart->id_address_invoice = 6;
          $cart->update();
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: probably an extra brace somewhere before the method.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the `public` modifier on a function that's outside of a class. Try removing it, and your problem should disappear.

Comment: Dissapear but the code dont work

Comment: Without more context, it's nearly impossible to help you fix this. What is this code doing, and what's not working?

Comment: i need remove the shipping method from prestashop i do the same steps of this link https://www.ner2.com/tutoriales/desactivar-metodo-de-envio-en-prestashop-1-7/